# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound by manually changing URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

The URL of a user in my application is as follows:

```
localhost:3000/users/1/dashboard
```

When someone manually changes the `user ID` in the URL to a number which doesn't have a user asigned to it, it gives me the error:

```
Couldn't find User with id=X.
```

Is there a way to return the user to somewhere else?

I tried something like this in user_controller.rb:

```
@user = User.find(params[:id])

unless @user
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

Comment: And what happened when you did that? Also, we may need to see more of the method where you included that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, for example:

```
def dashboard
  begin
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

ActiveRecord raises an exception if it can't find a record, that's why your `unless @user ...` is futile.

Answer (score 1):

Another way, without the need of resque, is to use find_by_id, that returns nil if no record is found:

```
def dashboard
  @user = User.find_by_id params[:id]
  redirect_to root_path unless @user
end
```

Comment: That is not correct, the find_by_...method is not deprecated. http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html#active-record

Comment: Thanks for the correction, I mixed it up with find_all_by methods. I fixed my anwer.